# проблема с jar файлом

Tags: java, jar

Сделал в Intellij jar файл. На моей пк все работает отлично. Проблема в том, что на пк других людей выводит следующее(см. скрины)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте обновить яву на машине, где запускаете или скомпилируйте более старой яве. Судя по ошибке именно так и решается сия проблема.

Comment: как скомпилить на более старой джавке?

Comment: Ну... Потереть новую, поставить старую, скомпилить

Comment: ну логично тогда, что не будет компилиться на новой

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Судя по сообщению программа компилировалась с помощью Java 9, а запустить вы пытаетесь под Java 8. Поможет использование ключа [target](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#BHCJDCID) командной строки компилятора. В IntelliJ IDEA этот параметр можно задать здесь:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]